# symfony2 forms: custom form element not referenced to doctrine2 object field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I'm trying to place a custom checkbox to form. This checkbox is not referenced to any doctrine2 object field. The checkbox is like "remember me" on signin form.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('login');
    $builder->add('password');
    $builder->add('remember_me');
}
```

No mapping found for field 'remember_me' in class ...

How should I solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use property_path option as :

> $builder->add('remember_me', 'checkbox', array('property_path' =>
>   false))